# Anyone aware of AWS Elastic Bean Stalk support for native ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

any examples that I can try out ?

Thanks

Comment: True. But you probably got down voted because you could have easily find out the answer yourself. A better question would be if you had something specific, like an error you cannot solve on your own. But don't let a simple down vote discourage you from asking questions if you ever need to. :)

Comment: thanks for your advice Mr. Tan, by the way you have interesting site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit of search turned up this: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk/